# Windows 7 history of opened files

Tags: windows, file-history

I opened a document probably a month ago, and I forgot its location. I want to know if Windows keeps a history of files opened that could help me retrieve that file from a list of opened files sorted by date. Sort of like a log or history of opened files. Thanks.

Comment: By default, Windows 7 does store a [list of recently opened files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/show-or-hide-recent-items-on-the-start-menu). It might not display the document you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a log doesn't exist, unless you specifically turned on File/Folder auditing (which would report to the Windows Event logs).

More info:

- [How to audit user access of files, folders, and printers in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399)
- [Auditing Access To Files On Windows 7](http://www.discoveryourpc.net/2010/01/auditing-access-to-files-on-windows-7.html)
- [Apply or Modify Auditing Policy Settings for a Local File or Folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070.aspx)
- [File Auditing in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/521945/file-auditing-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I looked up this thread because my wife was unable to find a word doc (.docx) that she knew she had edited that morning, but which someone else had moved.  I was able to find it by doing search of the c drive for *.docx, and then sorting the results by date modified.

A similar approach could work for other file types, not so much for files in general.

Comment: The tricky part about this particular situation is that your wife did edit the file. Where the question asker opened the file, but didn't necessarily edit it. If they have a clue of the file name, then this sort of option may help them out. There is also a File/Folder auditing feature that will log these kinds of things in Windows Event Viewer, but that won't help for a past scenario if it was not enabled beforehand.