# How can you identify what user or computer is running a batch file.

Tags: batch-file

We have taken over an environment from another IT department. There is a batch file  on a server. We want to know if it ever runs and if so what user or more importantly what remote computer on the same network is running this batch file.

Comment: The easiest way is to modify the batch file to log this information to a network share that all (likely) users of the script have access to.

Comment: I believe you can set up [file auditing](https://superuser.com/questions/521945/file-auditing-in-windows) and check the Event Viewer for Event 4656, looking for opening of a file.